# Plot the graph of the square wave function defined as $f(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n h_{n}(t)$ on the interval $t>0$ and find its Laplace transform

Tags: plotting, graphics, fourier-analysis

Plot the graph of the square wave function defined as $$f(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n h_{n}(t)$$ on the interval $t>0$ and find its Laplace transform. The http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html has FourierSeriesSquareWave but not exactly as the function above. Please, can anyone help out in plotting this graph and solving the problem? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I don't get you question. What is $h_n$?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: $h_n$ is heaviside function!

Comment: Oha. There is more then one Heaviside function? Really, poorly stated questions have a low chance to be answered properly. Please provide _all_ relevant information.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Okay, I'll do that!

Comment: Is this `f = Sum[(-1)^n*HeavisideTheta[t - n], {n, 0, 10}]
g = LaplaceTransform[f, t, s]
Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[g, { s, 0, 10}]` close to what you are looking for? Note: make sure each of those four expressions is on a separate line or in a separate cell in your notebook

Comment: @ Bill: Let me run those codes and get back at you!

Comment: @Bill: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`SquareWave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareWave) instead?

```
f[t_] := SquareWave[t/2]
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform):

```
LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

> Tanh[s/2]/s